# VSTS change time zone

Tags: azure-devops

Will changing global time zone in VSTS impact existing tasks, or it is a display option only? Have a customer that is considering to change this, but is concerned whether it can impact existing projects.

[image]

Comment: Do you clear it?

Comment: Yes jayendran's post solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different time zones in VSTS

1. VSTS account TimeZone
2. VSTS user profile TimeZone

### VSTS Account TZ

In the Question, you are mentioning about the VSTS Account TimeZone. This is the main TimeZone settings, where all your iteration dates, build/release schedule depends upon and etc.,.So by changing this will affect the dependencies.

### VSTS user profile TZ

This is the one which you need that it's only for UI showing.VSTS user profile time zone setting is used to make the user experience more personal to the user and display the VSTS timestamps for when a user browsing VSTS using time zone configured for that specific user.

**So, if my VSTS account time zone is set to EST, but my user profile time zone setting is set to PST, then when I'm browsing the VSTS all date/time fields will be displayed in PST time zone.**

VSTS user profile time zone setting can be configured on user profile page (https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me?mkt=en-US&campaign=o~msft~vsts~usercard), by clicking your name on the top-right corner of your VSTS page, then clicking on My Profile | Edit profile | Preferences option. Set your user time zone setting and click Save.

[Reference](https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2018/03/07/VSTS-Time-Zone-Settings.aspx)