# Check VSTS server time zone

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We commit our code to a VSTS server. How to check VSTS server timezone? I was able to find team member's time zone in their profile. But how to find VSTS server timezone?

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask, but why do you want to know this?

Comment: Server time zones should almost always be UTC, and also should almost always be irrelevant to your code.

Comment: If you are confused on the timezone,please have a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52176161/7073340)

Comment: @Jayendran thank you. This is what I was searching.

Comment: @MattJohnson I've provided the answer. Please accept/upvote it

Comment: Upvoted, thanks.  Only the author (kasun) can accept.  I am not a moderator.

Comment: @KasunG I've provided my answer, please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about the AzureDevOps Time Zone.

All the time Zone in AzureDevOps can be configurable. Basically, there are 2 types of Timezone in AzureDevOps

1. VSTS/AzureDevOps Account TimeZone-  It controls the Iteration dates, builds/release schedule Pipeline etc.,
2. VSTS/AzureDevOps user profile TimeZone - Only used for the UI purpose, based on the user profile we can control this.

Please see my detailed [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168972/vsts-change-time-zone/52176161#52176161)